# Flutter WebviewXPlus - problem with calling callback

Tags: flutter

I try to implement recaptcha in flutter, I'm basing half on this: https://protocoderspoint.com/flutter-recaptcha-verification-i-am-not-a-robot-validation/, but I'm using **webviewx_plus** package instead of **webview_flutter_plus**, because it runs both on mobile and web. Unfortunately dartCallbacks are not working for me. Here's code, what I tried to do is described later.

`WebViewX` widget

```dart
WebViewX(
 height: 100,
 width: 320,
 initialContent: 'about:blank',
 initialSourceType: SourceType.html,
 onWebViewCreated: (controller) => _setupWebView(controller),
 jsContent: const {
  EmbeddedJsContent(
   webJs:
   "function captchaCallback(msg) { Captcha('Web callback says: ' + msg) }",
   mobileJs:
   "function captchaCallback(msg) { Captcha.postMessage('Mobile callback says: ' + msg) }",
  ),
 },
 dartCallBacks: {
  DartCallback(
   name: 'Captcha',
   callBack: (msg) => print(msg.toString()),
  )
 },
),
```

`_setupWebView` function loading **recaptcha**

```dart
_setupWebView(controller){
      webviewController = controller;
      webviewController.loadContent(
          'https://any-url.pl/recaptcha.html',
          sourceType: SourceType.url,
      );
}
```

**recaptcha.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body style='background-color: white;'>
<form action="?" method="POST">
    <div class="g-recaptcha"
         data-sitekey="6LccLHspAAAAAK-u8sAFG0UEDHfUMVej7Y61Twxh"
         data-callback="captchaCallback"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I had to put recaptcha.html on remote server, because domain check didn't allowed me to run it from local html file. **Recaptcha** is now working but I got issue with receiving callback from it, if I put js function to html it gets executed but dartCallback defined in `WebViewX` widget somehow is not visible. I changed code so captchaCallback function which is calling dartcallback is now defined using `WebViewX` widget and now it doesn't see this js function. Resolving captcha results in console error: "ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: captchaCallback". I don't know what can be wrong, I did everything like in documentation.